# After turning off Store application, PC shuts down normally but quickly - why?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

So I've turned off “Microsoft Store application” from the Local Group Policy Editor (run > gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Store > Turn off the Store application > Enable) as you see.. wsappx was causing high cpu, disk and power usage.. and now, much to my surprise, the pc turns off quickly - like the screen, immediately (~1–3 sec), after choosing the shut down option and the CPU itself, after a few seconds. The entire shutdown process still takes a few seconds, and happens normally but that's definitely faster than before. Can someone please explain the reason? I'm on windows 10 Pro btw.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Something wrong in your OS.  No issue with Store Windows 10 or 11 multiple devices.